# Exponential decay

Tags: calculus, probability, exponential-function, percolation

During my study of percolation I came across exponential decay and there are some parts I do not understand about this.

The definition of exponential decay is as follows:

$f(t)$ decays exponentially means that there are parameters $c,\lambda$ such that $$
  f(t) = c\,e^{\lambda t} 
$$

Now in percolation theory they say that the tail of $C$ decays exponentially when
$$ P(|C|\geq n)\leq e^{-cn}$$
Why?

Furthermore they say that there is no exponential decay when
$$P(n\leq C<\infty)\geq e^{-cn^{(d-1)/d}}$$

Why?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that for this to be decay, we need $\lambda<0$. Your two inequalities appear to be definitions.  They are just saying that the LHS can be bounded (either from below or above) by an exponentially decaying function.

Comment: @Bey I see. But the inequalities are about the probability and the statements are about C, right?

Comment: Well, statements about various probabilities regarding C. The decay part is referring to the probabilities as a function of n.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. For the second inequality it is also important to note  that $e^{-n^{(d-1)/d}}\geq e^{-n}$ right?  To satisfy the like you said "definition".

Comment: Not sure what $d$ is, but I would agree that your condition should be true.

Comment: d is the dimension. So for the definition it is indeed needed to wright it in $e^{-n}$? Thanks!

Comment: The exponent is weird: For $d=1$ it reduces the RHS to a constant. Then it  asymptotically approaches 1.

Comment: Dimension $d\geq 2$

Comment: Ah, sorry, not familiar with percolation - of course $d>1$! is there still confusion on your part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30070/discussion-between-user202723-and-bey).

Comment: No it is fine. Thanks!